# Error while compiling lex file

Tags: lex

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
extern int yylval;
%}
%%
[a-zA-Z] { yylval= *yytext[0]; return ID; }
[0-9]    { yylval= *yytext[0]; return NUM;} 
.    return yytext[0];
\n   return 0;
%%
```

i'm compiling this lex file along with the yacc file, when I hit the following command (cc lex.yy.c y.tab.h -ll)the error is throwing for the above lex code (error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’))
Help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either remove the `*` or the `[0]` from `*yytext[0]`.

`yytext` is a pointer to `char`, so `yytext[0]` is a `char` and you cannot dereference a `char`, as the compiler is telling  you.